# Java Selenium test is unable to interact with Electron application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, electron

I would like to automate testing of an Electron app using Java+Selenium.
On stackoverflow I have seen a number of posts on this topic so I could understand that this can work.
But when I tried the same, I was only able to run the Electron application.
My test doesn't go further because it considers the window as already closed when it's still open.
I see the following:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
> from unknown error: web view not found
> (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.104)
> Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
> System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8.1'
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

And the code I'm running is below:

```
        String exePath = "C:\\AFBC\\my_electron.exe\\";
        String baseUrl = "http://localhost:9222";

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.setBinary(exePath);
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
        options.addArguments("--disable-setuid-sandbox");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Next']"));
```

Actually most of those driver options that you can see here I found on the Internet and they don't affect much the way it is working for me. I left them here so that you know what I have already tried.

Could someone please share their experience with this kind of automation projects, I would be very thankful.

I also tried to change the protocol to 4200 but this didn't seem to really affect.
I used a pre-installed Electron executable, maybe I should use another one from the local repository?..

Comment: Sorry I have to correct the first line of the code example, of course there should not be '\\' at the end, but this isn't the reason of my problem:
String exePath = "C:\\AFBC\\my_electron.exe";